# What is callback in URLs

Tags: javascript, callback, cross-domain

There are some cases in with Cross Domain Calls, I have used callback parameters in jQuery.ajax 's url parameter. And, I know it executes the function with a name that is passed in that argument.

But, I could not understand how it exactly works. I have to use many times "callback=?" and it executed whatever I wrote in $.ajax's success function. And, it didn't execute the named functions say "getUsers" if I pass *callback=getUsers*. It was just a way I observed working and I implemented, but could not get what exactly was causing difference here.

Can anyone please explain it.

Comment: [***JSONP***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: Yes, it's that. But I am more concerned about what made a difference which I have mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), take a look at the wiki entry. It's basically javascript taking advantage of the global namespace to force a data transfer that would otherwise not be possible due to browser security.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP isn't really ajax, it's just neatly wrapped in `$.ajax`, but what it really does is insert a `<script>` tag into the document, and the callback that you add to the end of the querystring is the function that the JSON is wrapped in inside that script.
In other words, requesting:

```
'http://www.somepage.com/link/to/getjsonp?callback=fn'
```

the server would generate code that looks like:

```
fn( {"name":"Ashmah", "type":"user"} );
```

that means the inserted script calls a function called fn(), and passes a JSON string as the parameter, so if you have such a function on your page, like so:

```
function fn(json) {
    // do something with json
}
```

Once the script is added to the document and has loaded, the function `fn()` is called so you can access the JSON string once the script has loaded, and that's how it avoids the same origin policy, as script tags can be cross domain, but XMLHttpRequests can't.

Comment: So, what happens when we write "callback=?". In my case it was  showing in firebug like "callback=jQuery17205197765840699152_1374055648690" and was executing $.ajax's - "success:function(result){}". and looking in DOM panel, each time I make a request, it was creating a variable winth "undefined" value. for the above call variable would be - jQuery17205197765840699152_1374055648690 with undefined.

Comment: jQuery will create a name for callback function, like `jQuery17205197765840699152_1374055648690`, and execute that function internally and port the result to the success handler in `$.ajax`, so you don't have to worry about the callback function.